# create a macro only with macro variables creation (%let) in sas

Tags: macros, sas

Hi I was trying to create a macro that only contains macro variable creation but it failed. Here is an example:

```
%macro createvariable; 
    %let a = 5;
    %let b = 6;
%mend createvariable;
%createvariable; 

data test; 
    c = &a + &b;
run;
```

But it will work as:

```
%macro createvariable; 
    %let a = 5;
    %let b = 6;
data test; 
    c = &a + &b;
run;
%mend createvariable;
%createvariable;
```

So I was wondering if SAS won't be able to create a macro with only macro variables creation in it? Or there is a way to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: I believe the issue is that macro variables created within a macro are local to that macro. If you want to create macro variables within a macro and allow them to be accessed outside that macro, then you have to declare them as global macro variables.

Comment: Grate! Thanks for the solution. I really learned.

Comment: Anyone know why this question has a down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
%macro createvariable; 
%global a b;
    %let a = 5;
    %let b = 6;
%mend createvariable;
%createvariable; 

data test; 
    c = &a + &b;
run;
```

Comment: A description of why the %GLOBAL statement is needed would improve this answer.